# Reading multiple result set from MSSQL stored procedure in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am fetching data from stored procedure in MSSQL Server 2012 (using SQLSRV driver), it is returning multiple result sets, but I am able to read just first result set using following code

```
$res = DB::select('EXEC Procedure_Name ?,?,?,?',
                    array(
                            $Prama1,
                            $Prama2,
                            $Prama3, 
                            $Prama4
                        ));
```

This returns four result sets, but when I print $res I am getting just the first result set, how to read other result sets ? Any hint would be of great help.

Update:

Found out some clue on stackoverflow and compile this solutions, dont know if it an optimized way to achieve this. please share if you have a better way to do this.

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare("EXEC Procedure_Name ?,?,?,?");

    $type = "Type";
    $fromDate = "01-Mar-2014";
    $toDate = "15-Mar-2014";
    $adminId = 0;
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $type);
    $stmt->bindParam(2 , $fromDate);
    $stmt->bindParam(3 , $toDate);
    $stmt->bindParam(4 , $adminId);
    $stmt->execute();

        $search = array();
    do {
         $search = $stmt->fetchAll();   

         print '<pre>'; print_r($search); 
    } while ($stmt->nextRowset());
```

Comment: Any reason for not using Eloquent and QueryBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

I dont remember well but, if you can, try to use:

> SET NOCOUNT ON

in your stored procedure declaration.

I think you can use then the default select() function like you did:

```
DB::select('EXEC Procedure_Name ?,?', $bindings)
```

And retrieve an array of results